# Is there a docker API or exec.Command way to retrieve container ID from a given container name (not list of containers)?

Tags: docker, go, containers

I am developing a go CUI for docker container. I need container ID for only selected container Name.

I tried it this way:

```
  id, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "docker", fmt.Sprintf("ps --no-trunc -aqf name=%s"),conName).Output()
  if err != nil {
         log.Fatal(err)
  }
  fmt.Println("CONTAINER ID:", id)
```

Output:

```
CONTAINER ID: []
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/

Comment: thanks for your comment, but this is not useful

Comment: Why not? It gives you exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me (may be you don't need sudo):

```
id, err := exec.Command("sudo", "docker", "ps", "--no-trunc", "-aqf", fmt.Sprintf("name=%s",conName)).Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println("CONTAINER ID:", string(id))
```

Your mistake was, that conName was not inside the parentheses and you also have to convert id to a string as exec.Command returns you a byte array. Also all arguments should be listed separately, if you place several arguments separated by whitespaces as one string, it won't work.